# smart Capture does not work with iphone

Tags: marketing-cloud, javascript, ssjs, cloudpage, developer

I have a smarcapture that I added this code snippet to pass by url a parameter of a question and it works in android and pc but it does not capture the IOS information.

````
const form = document.getElementById('smartcapture-block-c7s68z77vq');

   form.addEventListener('submit', () => {
   let Experience=document.getElementById('Experience')
   
  
  window.top.location.href = "https://www.example.com?Experience="+Experience.value; 
  
                             
 });
 
 </script> ```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was that I was using Javascript language and server side javascript should be used.